# AJAX HTTP error 500 while adding field to View in Drupal 7.20 (Sarnia

Tags: php, ajax, drupal, solr

I have installed Sarnia module and its dependencies in Drupal 7.20 to interact with external Solr data without any issues following http://drupal.org/node/1379476. After module installation, when I was creating Views of Solr data under the path 'Admin > Structure > Views', following error shows up while adding some of the fields (Solr property fields) to the View ,

-- Error message --

```
   An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 500 Debugging
   information follows. Path:
   /drupal/admin/structure/views/view/viewtest2/preview/page/ajax
   StatusText: error ResponseText: 500 - Internal server error Sever
   Error 500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the
   resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed
```

---

I could add few fields to the view without any error but I dont understand why this error shows up while adding some particular fields to the view? How to fix it? Please help

*** Please note that I am using IIS and not Apache ***

From admin/reports/recent logs I could find more information regarding the error:

EntityMetadataWrapperException: Invalid data value given. Be sure it matches the required data type and format. in EntityDrupalWrapper->set() (line 744 of C:\download\drupal\drupal\sites\all\modules\entity\includes\entity.wrapper.inc).

Comment: Can you tail error_log, it's seems that invalid .htaccess, missing some functions on php.ini or try increase memory. It may can be permission problem. Try put on .htaccess `php_value post_max_size 20971520
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off`

Comment: please advise where I can find the error_log? error log under drupal or php?

Comment: What are you using cpanel, VPS hosting or shared hosting? Or you are working on linux own system?

Comment: To see the logs, you should use drush, and use the command: `drush ws --full`. Drupal has its own way to store the logs. If your install is stll working, go to: admin/reports/dblog

Comment: For John comments look at http://drupal.org/project/drush module.

Comment: I am working on windows server 2008

Comment: tried adding 'php_value post_max_size 20971520          on' in .htaccess - i still see the issue

Comment: *** please note that I am using IIS and not Apache ***

Comment: From logs: EntityMetadataWrapperException: Invalid data value given. Be sure it matches the required data type and format. in EntityDrupalWrapper->set() (line 744 of C:\download\drupal\drupal\sites\all\modules\entity\includes\entity.wrapper.inc).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an image field added to the view? And if so, is the image linked to it's node via the "link field to its node" setting? If this is the case try to turn off this link setting and see if the error still occurs.

Comment: its not an image but rather "title" field. "link field to its node" is turned off as well. Some of the "title" field values are empty, that could have been the issue?